# Parse a dynamic nested JSON into Map<*, *> using Kotlinx.serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlinx.serialization, kotlinx

I need to parse any dynamic JSON (In the Kotlin Multiplatform project) to key-value pair and convert it to a nested list after. I started with the default `.toMap()` function, but it can't go deeper to parse ArrayList<*> Any idea how to do it?

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -3):

Your `@Serializable data class` should look like this:

```
@Serializable
data class MainClass(
    val id: String,
    val type: String,
    val batters: BatterClass,
    val topping: List<ToppingClass>,
)

@Serializable
data class BatterClass(
    val batter: List<BatterClassObject>
)

@Serializable
data class BatterClassObject(
    val id: String,
    val type: String, 
)

@Serializable
data class ToppingClass(
    val id: String,
    val type: String, 
)
```

Kotlinx.serialization should parse your json without any problems into `MainClass.serializable()`.

Comment: As I said, I need to parse any dynamic JSON, so it's not possible to create a data class in advance.

Comment: In that case, just specify root object as `JsonElement`, and deal with it once the serialization to it finishes.

Comment: @Webfreak That still is not the answer. Answer would be you can't do it with `kotlinx`. "Deserializing" string to `JsonElement` is much like parsing a string at run time without type safety

Comment: @Farid, if the json is dynamic, there is no other way but to parse it to JsonElement and then making a if-else check. For example: if(JsonElement is JsonObject) else if ( JsonElement is JsonArray)... etc.